# Python: CSV writer very slow, need advice to speed it up

Tags: python, performance, csv

I'm using a simple script to pull data from an Oracle DB and write the data to a CSV file using the CSV writer.

The table i'm querying contains about 25k records, the script runs perfectly except for its actually very slow. It takes 25 minutes to finish.

In what way could i speed up this by altering the code? Any tips from you heroes are welcome.

```
#
# Load libraries
#
from __future__ import print_function
import cx_Oracle
import time
import csv

#
# Connect to Oracle and select the proper data
#
con = cx_Oracle.connect('secret')
cursor = con.cursor()
sql = "select * from table"

#
# Determine how and where the filename is created
#
path = ("c:\\path\\")
filename = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
extentionname = (".csv")
csv_file = open(path+filename+extentionname, "w")

writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',', lineterminator="\n", 
quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)

r = cursor.execute(sql)
for row in cursor:
    writer.writerow(row)

cursor.close()
con.close()
csv_file.close()
```

Comment: If u use simple csv maybe it's faster to prepare schema in memory and dump it to file?

Comment: *"It takes 25 minutes to finish."*: How can you be sure that most of the time are consumed by `for row ... writer.writerrow(...`

Comment: Before altering the code, I'd put some simple `print(time.time())` calls in there to see what is taking so long. Also, test running the script only reading from the DB without actually writing anything. Maybe your database connection is just extremely slow for some reason.

Comment: It is unlikely that csv.writer. The first thing I would check if the "table" is really a table and not a view. Oracle optimizes the query to get the first 500 rows (assuming you are using SQL developer to test the SELECT). Or perhaps the table is very wide, which means you are downloading and writing a lot of data per row - even if that is only 25K.

Comment: On the cx_Oracle side, tune the fetch [`arraysize`](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cursor.html#Cursor.arraysize).  On the DB side, tune indexes. For Oracle Net tune [socket buffers and SDU size](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/oow17netcon6718-3944720.pdf).

Comment: It [has been reported](http://www.lucainvernizzi.net/blog/2015/08/03/8x-speed-up-for-python-s-csv-dictwriter/) that setting `extrasaction='ignore'` speeds things up considerably. I haven't seen this improvement personally, but maybe it works for some use cases?

Comment: i've found that ``extrasaction='ignore'`` does speed it up, but its relative to how many fields your csv has. I had a csv with only 3 fields and got a 20% improvement.

Comment: Just with some test data, I wrote a 1000x25000 set of data and it took 12 seconds.  Also FYI, `extrasaction` is only a parameter for `csv.DictWriter`, not `csv.writer`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using `writerows` function from csv module? Instead of writing each record one by one, it gives provision to write all at once. This should fasten up the things.

```
data = [] #data rows

with open('csv_file.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(data)
```

Alternatively, you can also use pandas module to write big chunk of data to CSV file. This method is explained with examples [here](https://codethreads.dev/python/convert-json-to-csv-in-python/).

Comment: Why would `writerows` be faster? The bottleneck is most probably in the "write to disk" part, since file IO is much slower than other operations

Comment: You are correct that file I/O operations can be a bottleneck when writing data to disk, and this can be optimised witth `writerows()` compared to `writerow()`.

`writerows()` can reduce the overhead of file I/O operations by allowing you to write multiple rows to the file in a single operation. When you use `writerow()`, each call to the function opens and writes to the file.

Comment: Can I have a source for that? AFAIK the file remains open as long as you have the file descriptor returned by `open`

Comment: With test data of 1000x25000, writerow vs. writerows was 12.098s vs 11.995s, a less than 1% speed-up and within measurement error, so practically no difference.